# Continuous delivery for a Java EE application

Tags: jakarta-ee, continuous-deployment

We have a Java EE web application that we want to put in a continuous delivery pipeline. I'm new to this and have a few questions - 
How will the pipeline look like? (Given we use Git/Jenkins/Maven/Artifactory) 
What are the tests that should be created and when should they be run?
Any other suggestions?

Thanks
Yana

Comment: We have the following pipeline: build (with unit tests) -> integration tests + SonarQube -> deploy on DEV stage -> deploy on QA stage -> deploy on PROD stage. The build is triggered by SCM, deploy jobs are manual. We use Jenkins [delivery pipeline plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Delivery+Pipeline+Plugin) for pipeline management. The deploy job does SCP of WAR file to server and restarts Tomcat via shell script (all included in our Gradle build script).

Comment: Thanks @SteffenHarbich - what cloud do you deploy to?

Comment: Also do you run all the tests as a part of the pipeline or are there other tests? If yes, when and how do you run them?

Comment: Deployment on own servers, additional systematic manual tests for every release.

Comment: Thanks Steffen - now I see the pipeline plugin doesn't have support for JUnit - what did you use as your unit testing framework?

Comment: TestNG, but it was sufficient for us to display the results in SonarQube, not in Jenkins.

Answer (score 1):

Stories are reviewed by the team prior to start of work. Don't time box (e.g. sprints), rather build stories in a continuous pipe. Test determines which tests will be automated and which will be performed manually. [Test pyramid](http://www.agilecoachjournal.com/2014-01-28/the-agile-testing-pyramid) comes into play. Use tools like [rest-assured](https://github.com/rest-assured/rest-assured) (Java) or [HTTParty](https://rubygems.org/gems/httparty/versions/0.13.7) et al for Ruby (plenty of choices with Ruby) to test web endpoints in the service layer (speed is key for CI).  Pure UI tests should be about 10% of the total automated tests. UI tests take the longest to run. Pick UI tests that exercise as much client side JavaScript as possible. You can use automated screenshot comparison tools like [Applitools](https://applitools.com/) et al to speed regression tests for UI. BTW, I only mention tools as for examples. I am not endorsing any tool or product. Do your own research.

Jenkins (or TeamCity) steps might look like:

1. Build App
2. (depends on step 1) run unit tests
3. (depends on step 2) run service layer tests
4. (depends on step 2) run UI layer tests
5. (depends on steps 3 & 4) deploy to Test

Once in Test, run any manual validations (e.g. look and feel).

Deploy to production once or more times a week (10 PM is popular).

Run automated production smoke (e.g. read-only tests that read DB/BI with service layer and compare to UI displayed values) to verify production deployment. Have tested back out procedures. :-)